# Linter marks property as non existing

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

[image: Example]I'm using SAPUI5 version 1.76.0 but the WebIDE is marking the property 'seperatorStyle' (got added in 1.5x or 1.6x can't remember) of

`<m:Breadcrumbs separatorStyle="GreaterThan" ... />`

as error ("Property or event name does not exist for the control.")

Autocomplete is giving me the property and the values for the property and it is working too, only the linter seems to have troubles.

I have verified in Project settings that my version is 1.76.0 and in the manifest under sap.ui5->dependancies I have `"minUI5Version": "1.76.0"` too.

Anyone an idea what may cause the linter to mark it as error ?

Comment: Looks like we can't do anything about it. The same happens with properties that were introduced in versions above 1.63 (e.g. `<ObjectStatus inverted="...">`). And Web IDE runs with 1.63 currently. Not sure if it's related.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the project XML validator to Basic will resolve the issue.

**Projet settings > XML > Validator = Basic XML**

[image: Setting option]

Comment: With basic validation it no longers triggers an error if entering an unknown property or if I have a typo in one name.

Comment: Yes you are right, will try to dig deep and find it. Hope someone might have the solution to it.